# Advanced if else statements with grep in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have following Jenkinsfile which will grep for a string from URL, it will send a notification to Slack depends upon the output.

```
stage('Check if present') {
    steps  {
        script{   
         sh """
          if curl -s http://example.foo.com:9000 | grep -q "ERROR"
            then  
              slackSend channel: '#team', message: "Pipeline has been failed due to due to an error, please investigate:${env.BUILD_URL} : http://example.foo.com:9000", teamDomain: 'example', tokenCredentialId: 'foo'    
                echo "Scan result: ERROR" && exit 1  
            elif curl -s http://example.foo.com:9000 | grep -q "WARN"
            then
           slackSend channel: '#team', message: "Pipeline is in WARN state due to a warning, please investigate:${env.BUILD_URL} : http://example.foo.com:9000", teamDomain: 'example', tokenCredentialId: 'foo'
             fi"""
         }
       }
    }
```

Absolutely the slackSend notification won't work, as it is a plugin.
I am looking for ways to do the same in Groovy so that I can implement slackNotification.

I tried the following logic in Groovy, as an example.
But it didn't work, as even if the line is not present is is printing line is found.

```
stage('test logic'){
steps{
 script{
     if ('curl -s http://example.foo.com:9000'.execute() | 'grep foo'.execute())
        println("The line is found")
     else {
         println("The line is not found")
         exit 1
     }
       }

}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use Groovy's (to be more accurate Java's) [.contains(String)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.String)) method to check if some string contains other string. Also when you execute command in pipeline you can capture stdout of that command.

Code:

```
stage('test logic'){
  steps{
   script{
     def commandStdout = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl -s http://example.foo.com:9000"
     if (commandStdout.contains("foo")) {
        println("The line is found")
     }else {
         println("The line is not found")
         exit 1
     }
   }
  }
}
```